# Keras Switch operation

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

Can Keras.Backend.Switch() function be used in the layers of a model?

I have a situation in which at certain layers, there will be branching into 3 different layers. But the forward and backward operations need to only pass through one of the 3 branches at this layer.

I was thinking of using K.switch at these layers. Will it work out? Will the backpropagation work when K.switch() is used in the model layers?

Comment: Yes, it will work out. Do you have any questions about the implementation?

Comment: How do I incorporate it as a trainable layer? I tried using lambda layer, but lambda layer isn't trainable. Do you have any idea?@rvinas

Comment: You can create a [custom keras layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/)

Comment: I created a custom layer, but still not working well, I have a created a new post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101593/conditional-batch-normalization-in-keras  @rvinas