# Conditional Batch Normalization in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to implement Conditional Batch Normalization in Keras. I assumed that I will have to create a custom layer, hence, I extended from the [Normalization](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py) source code from Keras team.

The idea:
I will have 3 conditions, so, I will need 3 different beta and gamma parameters to be initialized. Then, I just incorporated conditional statements where its needed. Note that my condition changes after every iteration randomly and trying to set the condition based on 3 global Keras variables, c1, c2, and c3.

Here is the code I have currently. It gives me error because of the conditional statements. Any idea how to improve or implement Conditional Batch Normalization in Keras:

UPDATED:

```
from keras import regularizers, initializers, constraints
from keras.legacy import interfaces
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer, Input, InputSpec
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf

global c1, c2, c3
c1 = K.variable([0])
c2 = K.variable([0])
c3 = K.variable([0])

class ConditionalBatchNormalization(Layer):
"""Conditional Batch normalization layer.
"""

@interfaces.legacy_batchnorm_support
def __init__(self, 
             axis=-1,
             momentum=0.99,
             epsilon=1e-3,
             center=True,
             scale=True,
             beta_initializer='zeros',
             gamma_initializer='ones',
             moving_mean_initializer='zeros',
             moving_variance_initializer='ones',
             beta_regularizer=None,
             gamma_regularizer=None,
             beta_constraint=None,
             gamma_constraint=None,
             **kwargs):
    super(ConditionalBatchNormalization, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.axis = axis
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.epsilon = epsilon
    self.center = center
    self.scale = scale
    self.beta_initializer = initializers.get(beta_initializer)
    self.gamma_initializer = initializers.get(gamma_initializer)
    self.moving_mean_initializer = initializers.get(moving_mean_initializer)
    self.moving_variance_initializer = (
        initializers.get(moving_variance_initializer))
    self.beta_regularizer = regularizers.get(beta_regularizer)
    self.gamma_regularizer = regularizers.get(gamma_regularizer)
    self.beta_constraint = constraints.get(beta_constraint)
    self.gamma_constraint = constraints.get(gamma_constraint)


def build(self, input_shape):

    dim = input_shape[0][self.axis]
    if dim is None:
        raise ValueError('Axis ' + str(self.axis) + ' of '
                         'input tensor should have a defined dimension '
                         'but the layer received an input with shape ' +
                         str(input_shape[0]) + '.')

    shape = (dim,)

    if self.scale:
        self.gamma1 = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                     name='gamma',
                                     initializer=self.gamma_initializer,
                                     regularizer=self.gamma_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.gamma_constraint)
        self.gamma2 = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                     name='gamma',
                                     initializer=self.gamma_initializer,
                                     regularizer=self.gamma_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.gamma_constraint)
        self.gamma3 = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                     name='gamma',
                                     initializer=self.gamma_initializer,
                                     regularizer=self.gamma_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.gamma_constraint)
    else:
        self.gamma1 = None
        self.gamma2 = None
        self.gamma3 = None

    if self.center:
        self.beta1 = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                    name='beta',
                                    initializer=self.beta_initializer,
                                    regularizer=self.beta_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.beta_constraint)

        self.beta2 = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                    name='beta',
                                    initializer=self.beta_initializer,
                                    regularizer=self.beta_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.beta_constraint)

        self.beta3 = self.add_weight(shape=shape,
                                    name='beta',
                                    initializer=self.beta_initializer,
                                    regularizer=self.beta_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.beta_constraint)
    else:
        self.beta1 = None
        self.beta2 = None
        self.beta3 = None

    self.moving_mean = self.add_weight(
        shape=shape,
        name='moving_mean',
        initializer=self.moving_mean_initializer,
        trainable=False)
    self.moving_variance = self.add_weight(
        shape=shape,
        name='moving_variance',
        initializer=self.moving_variance_initializer,
        trainable=False)

    super(ConditionalBatchNormalization, self).build(input_shape) 

def call(self, inputs, training=None):

    input_shape = K.int_shape(inputs[0])
    c1 = inputs[1][0]
    c2 = inputs[2][0]

    # Prepare broadcasting shape.
    ndim = len(input_shape)
    reduction_axes = list(range(len(input_shape)))
    del reduction_axes[self.axis]
    broadcast_shape = [1] * len(input_shape)
    broadcast_shape[self.axis] = input_shape[self.axis]

    # Determines whether broadcasting is needed.
    needs_broadcasting = (sorted(reduction_axes) != list(range(ndim))[:-1])

    def normalize_inference():
        if needs_broadcasting:
            # In this case we must explicitly broadcast all parameters.
            broadcast_moving_mean = K.reshape(self.moving_mean,
                                              broadcast_shape)
            broadcast_moving_variance = K.reshape(self.moving_variance,
                                                  broadcast_shape)
            if self.center:
                broadcast_beta = \
                    tf.case({
                                c1: lambda: K.reshape(self.beta1,
                                                      broadcast_shape),
                                c2: lambda: K.reshape(self.beta2,
                                                      broadcast_shape)
                            },
                                default=lambda: K.reshape(self.beta3,
                                                          broadcast_shape)
                            )

            else:
                broadcast_beta = None

            if self.scale:

                broadcast_gamma = \
                    tf.case({
                                c1: lambda: K.reshape(self.gamma1,
                                                      broadcast_shape),
                                c2: lambda: K.reshape(self.gamma2,
                                                      broadcast_shape)
                            },
                                default=lambda: K.reshape(self.gamma3,
                                                          broadcast_shape)
                            )

            else:
                broadcast_gamma = None

            return K.batch_normalization(
                inputs[0],
                broadcast_moving_mean,
                broadcast_moving_variance,
                broadcast_beta,
                broadcast_gamma,
                axis=self.axis,
                epsilon=self.epsilon)
        else:
            out = \
            tf.case({
                    c1: lambda: K.batch_normalization(
                                        inputs[0],
                                        self.moving_mean,
                                        self.moving_variance,
                                        self.beta1,
                                        self.gamma1,
                                        axis=self.axis,
                                        epsilon=self.epsilon),
                    c2: lambda: K.batch_normalization(
                                        inputs[0],
                                        self.moving_mean,
                                        self.moving_variance,
                                        self.beta2,
                                        self.gamma2,
                                        axis=self.axis,
                                        epsilon=self.epsilon)
                },
                    default=lambda: K.batch_normalization(
                                        inputs[0],
                                        self.moving_mean,
                                        self.moving_variance,
                                        self.beta3,
                                        self.gamma3,
                                        axis=self.axis,
                                        epsilon=self.epsilon)
                        )

            return out

    # If the learning phase is *static* and set to inference:
    if training in {0, False}:
        return normalize_inference()


    # If the learning is either dynamic, or set to training:
    normed_training, mean, variance = \
        tf.case({
                    c1: lambda: K.normalize_batch_in_training(
                            inputs[0], self.gamma1, self.beta1, reduction_axes,
                            epsilon=self.epsilon),
                    c2: lambda: K.normalize_batch_in_training(
                            inputs[0], self.gamma2, self.beta2, reduction_axes,
                            epsilon=self.epsilon)
                },
                    default=lambda: K.normalize_batch_in_training(
                            inputs[0], self.gamma3, self.beta3, reduction_axes,
                            epsilon=self.epsilon)
                )

    print(normed_training)

    if K.backend() != 'cntk':
        sample_size = K.prod([K.shape(inputs[0])[axis]
                              for axis in reduction_axes])
        sample_size = K.cast(sample_size, dtype=K.dtype(inputs[0]))
        if K.backend() == 'tensorflow' and sample_size.dtype != 'float32':
            sample_size = K.cast(sample_size, dtype='float32')

        # sample variance - unbiased estimator of population variance
        variance *= sample_size / (sample_size - (1.0 + self.epsilon))

    self.add_update([K.moving_average_update(self.moving_mean,
                                             mean,
                                             self.momentum),
                     K.moving_average_update(self.moving_variance,
                                             variance,
                                             self.momentum)],
                    inputs[0])

    # Pick the normalized form corresponding to the training phase.

    return K.in_train_phase(normed_training,
                            normalize_inference,
                            training=training)

def get_config(self):
    config = {
        'axis': self.axis,
        'momentum': self.momentum,
        'epsilon': self.epsilon,
        'center': self.center,
        'scale': self.scale,
        'beta_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.beta_initializer),
        'gamma_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.gamma_initializer),
        'moving_mean_initializer':
            initializers.serialize(self.moving_mean_initializer),
        'moving_variance_initializer':
            initializers.serialize(self.moving_variance_initializer),
        'beta_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.beta_regularizer),
        'gamma_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.gamma_regularizer),
        'beta_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.beta_constraint),
        'gamma_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.gamma_constraint)
    }
    base_config = super(ConditionalBatchNormalization, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

    return input_shape[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Input((10,))
    c1 = Input(batch_shape=(1,), dtype=tf.bool)
    c2 = Input(batch_shape=(1,), dtype=tf.bool)
    h = ConditionalBatchNormalization()([x, c1, c2])
    model = Model([x, c1, c2], h)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-4), loss='mse')

    c1 = K.constant([False]*100, dtype=tf.bool)
    c2 = K.constant([True]*100, dtype=tf.bool)

    X = np.random.rand(100, 10)
    Y = np.random.rand(100, 10)


    model.train_on_batch(x=[X, c1, c2], y=Y)

    c1 = K.constant([False]*100, dtype=tf.bool)
    c2 = K.constant([True]*100, dtype=tf.bool)


    model.train_on_batch(x=[X, c1, c2], y=Y)
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [tf.case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case) to express your conditional statements:

```py
normed_training, mean, variance = \
            tf.case({
                c1: lambda: K.normalize_batch_in_training(
                    inputs, self.gamma1, self.beta1, reduction_axes,
                    epsilon=self.epsilon),
                c2: lambda: K.normalize_batch_in_training(
                    inputs, self.gamma2, self.beta2, reduction_axes,
                    epsilon=self.epsilon)
            },
                default=lambda: K.normalize_batch_in_training(
                    inputs, self.gamma3, self.beta3, reduction_axes,
                    epsilon=self.epsilon)
            )
```

Note also that [tf.case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case) requires the conditions `c1` and `c2` to be of type [tf.Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), so I defined them as follows:

```py
c1 = K.constant(False, dtype=tf.bool)
c2 = K.constant(False, dtype=tf.bool)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Now, I will have to change the conditions during training after each iteration. I was planning to do that by changing the c1, c2, and c3 values. But, if we define them as constants, we can't we change that during training right? How do we deal with this? Will re-initialization works and change the graph computations follow accordingly? @rvinas

Comment: I just tested, it seems like it always follows the initial conditions. For example, if we set, c1 to be True and the rest to be False, only gamma1 and beta1 are getting updated during training. Is there workaround to have the backend to follow the new values of c1, c2 and c3?

Comment: I would define the conditions `c1` and `c2` as placeholders (using the Keras [Input](https://keras.io/layers/core/#Input) layer) so that you can choose and feed their values during training

Comment: Thanks, I somehow implemented the custom layer and made 2 extra inputs for the layer. However, the layer is not working as intended. There are 8 weight arrays for this layer (beta1, beta2, beta2, gamma1, gamma2, gamma3, moving_average, moving_variance). Based on the main function above that I tried, the moving_average and moving_variance are not being updated. Also, the beta and gamma weights are not being updated correctly, i.e, weights of gamma2 and gamma3 are still being changed when the condition c1=True. I'm not sure what else is causing the problem. Any idea? @rvinas

Comment: This seems like a different problem. Could you please post another question? Also, make sure your error is reproducible (your code doesn't work on my machine!) and minimal. Best wishes!

Comment: Okay, I just created another post, thanks again! @rvinas